# how to check if edittext with input type decimal is empty?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an edittext named alt. its input type is decimal number. and i m not able to catch null pointer exception. If the edittext is empty or if no value is entered then my app crashes. i have searched a lot in stackoverflow but could not find solution. 
i have tried using the following

```
alt.getText().toString().equals("");
alt.getText().toString().matches("");
alt.getText().toString().contains("");
alt.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
Textutill.isEmpty(alt.getText());
```

What i do in the try/catch statement

here is my code

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/eps"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
    android:text="500"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.056" />
```

java

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_abu);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    alt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eps);
    public void calculateABU() {
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            altValue = Float.valueOf(alt.getText().toString());
             try{
                if (altValue > 10000 || altValue < -400) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-400 <= Altitude <= 10000 m", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(alt.getText())){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your `altValue = Float.valueOf(alt.getText().toString());` statement is outside the try block. Add into the try block & see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Nullcheck before conveting to float

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(alt.getText().toString())){
                altValue = Float.valueOf(alt.getText().toString());
                 if (altValue > 10000 || altValue < -400) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "-400 <= Altitude <= 10000 m", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you